# Accuracy differences when using custom activation functions in neural network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, activation-function

**Note: The logistic activation function already exists in tf.nn.logistic. However, I am trying to develop a custom activation which is on similar lines. Please refer to the code snippet below.**

```py
def custom_logistic(x):
    value= tf.to_float(tf.math.exp(-x))
    Activate_input = 1/(1+value)
    return Activate_input
```

Now, when I am calling the above function at the input layer of the code:

```py
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3, activation=custom_logistic))
```

**Note: Here, the model is a sequential model.**

I get an accuracy that is lesser than what I get when I use activation = tf.nn.sigmoid

Is there anything else I need to define?. Please let me know.

Comment: In your function, what is `mx` ?

Comment: Import mxnet as mx

Comment: You can use numpy arrays or Tensorflow tensors with Tensorflow; you can't use MXNet tensors.

Comment: Thank you! It works when I am using (1/1+tf.to_float(tf.math.exp(-x))), but the accuracy is low. I will edit my question to make it clear. Kindly, look into it.

Comment: Are you missing brackets? Try " (1/(1+tf.to_float(tf.math.exp(-x))))"....

Comment: It did not make any difference to the results @Andy Schroff. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Hi @Mitra Lanka, Can you provide a minimum reproducible code and an example screenshot of your model's accuracy?

Comment: @MitraLanka, Hi.  have reproduced your case but have seen no difference in the Accuracy even with the Custom Activation function. `tf.to_float` has resulting in error and `tf.cast` has resolved that error. If your issue is still not resolved, please share the complete code so that we can help you. Thanks!